# How to pass request header information to Angular6 app (JWT send by request header)

Tags: angular, express, jwt

- Usermanagement / Session management via other external App (for example Web application firewall WAF)
- external App sends JWT with User information in request Header to app
- Angular6 app needs the Information from the request Header ... ???

The Angular app should display some user information. 
The User Management is done by an external Application which only redirects authenticated Users to the Angular App and adds User information in the Request Header.
There is no Service API to request the user information. The user information is send to the app only via the request header (only available on the external server side).

How can I read/pass the user information to the angular app?

Intention:
* Express Proxy to serve angular app and forward request header information. Because angular has no possibility to read the request header.

The idea is to write a proxy to serve the angular app. This proxy for example a express app could read the request header and pass this to the angular app.

I'm able to serve the angular app but (1) how can I pass the header information? --> How to pass Variables/Data to Angular App?

---

Not so important Question because there are some librarys:
(2) how to decode the jwt and verify it (signed jwt) and pass only some information from the payload.

To server the angular app my express code looks like this:

---

```
const html = __dirname + '/angularApp/dist/angularApp';

const http = require('http');
const port = 4000;

// Express
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

app // config to serve angular app
    .use(compression())
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    // Static content
    .use(express.static(html));

app // Start server
    .listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Port: ' + port);
        console.log('Html: ' + html);
    });
```

File structure:

```
- root
-- server.js
-- angularApp
--- dist
---- angularApp
----- ... angular app build files
--- ... angular app files
```

Expected Result: 
The Angular App displays the user data which is send via request header.

Actual Result:
Angular App does not get any user data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a library to decode the jwt, e.g.

```
npm install jsonwebtoken
```

I don't see any code to handle incoming requests yet, did you miss it?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which I would like to point you out for improvement.

You should not use express to serve Angular App , unless you are using [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) for SSR. Because using Express to serve angular app is not at all optimised.

You don't need to decode JWT for showing the user information. Hence its best if you create a proxy api using Nginx which would be called by the client to get the JWT, when the Angular code executes in the client side.

Comment: The issue is that I have to make a app where the first call to the app contains in the request the JWT in the header. (The JWT is send by the WAF which is redirecting the call to the app within the Request Header...)